# Unknown command line argument '-polly'

Tags: clang, llvm

Installed LLVM, Clang and polly through http://polly.llvm.org/polly.sh.

after installation, clang is working fine however polly is not getting recognized.

is there and path that must be set.

Comment: Had this same issue, did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I use the manual method (https://polly.llvm.org/get_started.html) to build llvm with polly and clang.

Then I used the polly.sh script to build everything and now everything works fine. I didn't have to set any path. Just installed after running the script.